# ebay PHP SDK (unoffical) SetShipmentTracking Taking Sooo Long

Tags: php, rest, soap, ebay-api

So I'm using the unofficial ebay PHP SDK and updating shipment information works fine. However, it takes ages, literally about a minute and a half for the page to finally respond. After some debugging it seems the progress tracker is the issue. Every 5 / 6 seconds it checks the status, which is 'InProcess'. This gets checked around 11 times which amounts to over a minute. My question is, is it supposed to take that long to update tracking courier name and tracking number for one order?

This is the portion of code that gets the status

```
     $getJobStatusRequest = new BulkDataExchange\Types\GetJobStatusRequest();
     $getJobStatusRequest->jobId = $createUploadJobResponse->jobId;
     $done = false;
     while (!$done) {
         $getJobStatusResponse = $exchangeService->getJobStatus($getJobStatusRequest);
         if (isset($getJobStatusResponse->errorMessage)) {
             foreach ($getJobStatusResponse->errorMessage->error as $error) {
                 printf(
                     "%s: %s\n\n",
                     $error->severity === BulkDataExchange\Enums\ErrorSeverity::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
                     $error->message
                 );
             }
         }
         if ($getJobStatusResponse->ack !== 'Failure') {
             printf("Status is %s\n".' ** TIME: '.date('H:i:s').'. **', $getJobStatusResponse->jobProfile[0]->jobStatus);
             switch ($getJobStatusResponse->jobProfile[0]->jobStatus) {
                 case BulkDataExchange\Enums\JobStatus::C_COMPLETED:
                     $downloadFileReferenceId = $getJobStatusResponse->jobProfile[0]->fileReferenceId;
                     $done = true;
                     break;
                 case BulkDataExchange\Enums\JobStatus::C_ABORTED:
                 case BulkDataExchange\Enums\JobStatus::C_FAILED:
                     $done = true;
                     break;
                 default:
                     sleep(5);
                     break;
             }
         } else {
             $done = true;
         }
     }
```

Let me know if posting the whole script may be useful.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's something I don't understand. If you are updating just one order, why are you using BulkDataExchange? Why not just use the Trading\Types\CompleteSaleRequestType?
There you can use

```
...
$request->Shipment = new Trading\Types\ShipmentType();
$data = new Trading\Types\ShipmentTrackingDetailsType();
$data->ShipmentTrackingNumber = $track;
$data->ShippingCarrierUsed = $carrier;
$request->Shipment->ShipmentTrackingDetails = [$data];
$response = $service->CompleteSale($request);
```

and then you can check the ack to see if it was updated or not.

```
if($response->Ack != 'Failure'){
    // Failed
} else {
    // Updated. There might be warnings (The Ack would be Warning)
}
```

That's what I am using to update the trackings to my orders, and it takes 1, maybe 2 seconds. 
One thing is very clear. Updating one order should not take that long...

This is the entire call I use:

```
$service = new TradingServices\TradingService([
        'credentials' => [
                'appId'     => 'MY_APP_ID',
                'devId'     => 'MY_DEV_ID',
                'certId'    => 'MY_CERT_ID',
        ],
        'sandbox'   => false,
        'siteId'    => $siteId,
    ]);
    $request = new TradingTypes\CompleteSaleRequestType();
    $request->RequesterCredentials = new TradingTypes\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
    $request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $token;

    $request->ItemID = $itemid;
    $request->Shipped = true;
    $request->TransactionID = $transid;

    if( (!empty( $track ) ) && !empty( $shipper ) ){
        $request->Shipment = new TradingTypes\ShipmentType();
        $data = new TradingTypes\ShipmentTrackingDetailsType();
        $data->ShipmentTrackingNumber = $track;
        $data->ShippingCarrierUsed = $shipper;
        $request->Shipment->ShipmentTrackingDetails = [$data];
    }
    $response = $service->CompleteSale($request);
```

Comment: The reason you don't understand it is because i don't understand it!! lol. That being said, this of course looks like the right way of doing it so will try it asap and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Could you show me the rest of the page if possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the entire call I am using. If you need help, I would gladly skype you, or something... It should only take a few minutes to implement it.

Comment: Great answer. Very kind of you, can’t wait to try it. Will update you when I can.

Comment: So, i am now using your code and it takes a split second :D Man thanks so much!!

Comment: Very glad to hear that. I would appreciate it if you would approve the answer.